# jQuery script tested in jsFiddle is not working in firefox

Tags: jquery

I have textarea in a table and would like to resize textarea by click. I tested script in jsFiddle but it's not working in my project. Than I connected to script to simply page but without success. jQuery is connected, another script works, css is connected.

Here's the code:

```
$('textarea').click(function(){
    $('textarea').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('textareastyle');
});
```

According [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dimaomni/gdVRh/)

Tested with Firefox 20.0 and jQuery 1.9.1 (minified)

Comment: What errors do you see in firebug?

Answer (score 1):

Write your code in: DOM

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('textarea').click(function(){
          $('textarea').removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('textareastyle');
     });    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.focus()` and `.blur()` instead of `.click()`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdVRh/3/)

```
$('textarea').focus(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('textareastyle');
});
$('textarea').blur(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('textareastyle');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the compiled code from your jsFiddle:

```
<html>                                                                  
    <head>                                                                  
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>        
         <script type="text/javascript">                                         
            $(document).ready(function() {
                  $('textarea').click(function(){
                      $('textarea').removeClass('active');
                      $(this).addClass('textareastyle');
                 });    
            });                         
         </script>
         <style>
             .textareastyle{
                width: 300px; 
                height:300px; 
                position: fixed;
                margin-top:-2%;
                margin-left:30%;
                background-color:yellow;
                color: black;
            }
        </style>                                      
    </head>                                                                 
<body>                                                                  
   <textarea class="dd"></textarea>                                    
</body>                                                                 
</html>
```

It works in Firefox as well as in Chromium.

Remember to wrap code like this in the `$(document).ready()` method, so it's getting evaluated when the DOM is loaded.

Have a look at [the beginner's tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery) as well as the [API doc](http://api.jquery.com/).